# Find the minimum value of $x+y+z$ for positive exponents $x,y,z$?

Tags: exponentiation

> $x,y,z$ are positive integers, for equation $$2^{3x}+2^{5y}=2^{7z}$$ find the minimum value for $x+y+z$.

I am not sure is it possible to find all $x,y,z$ pairs. If so, can you provide a strategy for it?

Comment: $2^{3x+5y} = 2^{7z} \implies 3x + 5y = 7z$  There are only a handful of triplets to check before you find the one with the smallest sum

Comment: From $1=2^{7z-3x}-2^{5y-3x}$ you conclude that $7z-3x=1$ and $5y-3x=0$.

Comment: I solved the problem with your hint @MichaelHoppe thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that, you're welcome.